# Actuator Healthcheck for Third party APIs

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Suppose I have an API which calls another 
API and I want to have a health check of this endpoint as well. Is this possible with Actuator or do I need to write custom code?

Comment: I think that actuator is the best (or more famous) solution...

Comment: What is exactly that "another" API you want to test? You cannot test third party health with Actuator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement custom health indicator by implementing `org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator` and adding it as bean in spring context. Something like below should get you started:

```
@Component
public class CustomHealthCheck implements HealthIndicator {

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        int errorCode = check();
        if (errorCode != 0) {
            return Health.down()
              .withDetail("Error Code", errorCode).build();
        }
        return Health.up().build();
    }

    public int check() {
        // Custom logic to check health
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ..this is what i was looking for